# Still able to build despite errors when switching from ComponentActivity() to AppCompatActivity() in Jetpack Compose, Kotlin, Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm switching from `ComponentActivity()` to `AppCompatActivity()`, but things are a little weird, including:

- `setContent()` is red and showing the error: `None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch` -- but I'm still able to build.
- I've commented out `implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"` and `implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:$appcompat_version"` in my `<module> build.gradle` and synced -- and I'm still able to build.
- I've invalidated the cache, restarted Android Studio, and cleaned the project. No change -- still a red `setContent()`, and I can build.

Something is in a weird state, so I don't want to commit and share my code with colleagues, but I can't tell what is or is not working. Any ideas for why this is behaving this way?

```
    import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

    class MyViewerActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            setContent { // Red and error: None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch -- but it's still building
                MyTheme {
                    MyMenu()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's strange that I'm still able to build. I even have AppCompatActivity commented out in `build.gradle`, and I've synced.

```
// build.gradle

//    AppCompatActivity
//    def appcompat_version = "1.6.1"
//    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
//    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:$appcompat_version"
```

Comment: I've had the same issue for months now, can't figure it out.

Comment: I was now able to resolve this in my project. I realized I didn't get the error until I modularized my project. Moving `implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"` out of my :app module and into one of my core modules, the false errors went away.

Comment: And more specifically, I had to put it after my firebase dependencies. So weird...

Comment: way to go, Google.